# Failure of click action on input file element in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am trying to do click action on an input file element at Firefox extension side, but the upload dialog cannot be triggered.

I use

```
element.click()
```

at extension side, it fails. but it succeeds when executed at Firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent

it links to example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/event.initMouseEvent

```
var simulateClick = function(){
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 80, 20, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    document.getElementById('id of your element').dispatchEvent(evt);
}
simulateClick();
```